# How to create the equivalent of a spreadsheet?

Tags: 7

I don't want to start with too many unnecessary details on this one. I've got a stack of codes. Weekly more codes are added. On occasion these codes will be 'used' by other systems. These other systems are not Drupal sites.

I'm not sure how else to describe this, but all I want is the equivalent of a spreadsheet in Drupal: It should be possible to add rows, and delete rows of data on a single page, instead of creating a new node for every single code. I just want a table where I can add and delete codes, something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/jTable.aspx), a CRUD table.

My current solution is this:

1. Build a table (my_codes (id, code) )
2. Create a CRUD for the table so someone can manually enter in new codes (one by one)
3. Create a REST for the crud so these other systems can use these codes (codes/list, codes/add, codes/delete)

However, the main site is in Drupal, and only certain users should be able to add codes.

What is the simplest way to achieve this goal?
I could do all this work in a block, but I'd prefer to just install a Drupal module. If I can achive #1 and #2 with a module, then I should be able to do #3 myself. Note that last time I looked at CCK it did not have a "table" option.

Comment: In this case I think the details are necessary.

Comment: Have you looked into the Taxonomy module yet? I haven't spent much time with it, but you could be able to use it and CCK together to come up with something.

Comment: the simplest way is  to make a basic content type with a title and a body and give permission access to that. No additional module is needed. If this is not wht you are looking for then you need to give more details

Answer (score 1):

The [TableField](https://drupal.org/project/tablefield) or the [Slickgrid](https://drupal.org/project/slickgrid) modules may help here.

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal model is that you can have an Entity representing a DB table, and then you display entities however you please. So if Drupal is to be the front end for managing the database of codes, then other systems can still use the DB without having to know how to resolve attached fields.

Views gives you tables which you can sort. Inline editing would be something you'd have to add.. A search brings me to this project: http://drupal.org/project/jeditable Representing functions as icons (trash for delete, etc) could be a formatter, or a form alter in the theming.

And voila: You've made Excel in Drupal. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The [Views Bulk Operations module](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) could come in handy for you. It gives you a chance to add actions to a views table.

The Drupal standard security mechanism should be enough for you to make sure only a specific group of people have permission to create new data. You can define any number of roles and give them the permission to create your new content type.

To give a 3rd party system easy access to your Drupal data, you could use views and present your data as RSS feeds. You could also use views to get the node data as CVS files.

You might have to code a little bit for the Views Bulk Operation actions. Everything else should be possible with Drupal core and [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).